# Animation support for android homescreen widgets

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there an elegant way to add short animations to android homescreen widgets in modern android (API 30+)? I understand widgets are not meant to handle constant animation, but this animation would be triggered once every 30 minutes or so.

Within my widget class, I tried using an AnimationDrawable object to animate two images (although eventually I would like to do more frames). However, this did not work and resulted in a static image.

```java
public class CustomWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            // Create a RemoteViews object to specify the widget's layout
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

            // Create an AnimationDrawable
            AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();

            // Add each frame dynamically
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                        "frame_" + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

                if (drawableId != 0) {
                    Drawable frameDrawable = context.getDrawable(drawableId);
                    animationDrawable.addFrame(frameDrawable, /* frame duration in milliseconds */ 1000);
                }
            }

            // Set the AnimationDrawable as the background of the ImageView
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.animation_view, ((BitmapDrawable) animationDrawable.getFrame(0)).getBitmap());

            // Start the animation
            animationDrawable.start();

            // Update the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```